# How to register an MSN email account (googling the link doesn’t work anymore)

Tags: windows-live-messenger, account-management

Today I wanted to register an MSN email account (eg. abcname@msn.com), but the link that previously worked doesn’t work anymore.

https://accountservices.passport.net/reg.srf?ns=msn.com&sl=1&lc=2057
https://accountservices.passport.net/reg.srf?ns=msn.com&sl=1&lc=1033

Do you have any idea how can I register a new MSN email account?

Comment: msn email no longer exists only outlook.com does.  Its not currently possible to get a msn email address.

Answer (score 4):

MSN email is closed. It has been replaced by [Outlook.com](http://outlook.com/). Try registering there.